# When do I use which way to access the UI thread?

Tags: android, multithreading, user-interface

According to the documentation one of three options should be used for accessing the UI thread from a different thread.
These are the options:

1. Activity.runOnUiThread(Runnable)
2. View.post(Runnable)
3. View.postDelayed(Runnable, long)

When should I use which? They all seem to add a Runnable to the message queue of the UI thread.

I assume postDelayed is only really useful if you want to schedule a Runnable for later and they only mentioned it because it also runs the Runnable on the UI thread.

And for extra confusion there is also AsyncTask. When should I use that now?

Answer (score 1):

**runOnUiThread** and **View.post** are exactelly the same they both send a runnable object to the activity's **Handler** . so use whichever you like.

Regarding the **AsynchTask** it is not used to run on the UI thread. but after an Asynch task finishes working it calls a method called `OnPostExcute` on the UI thread.

There is a very great tutorial on this subject [Here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidPerformance/article.html)

Answer (score 1):

If you need a mechanism for returning to the UI thread that is available from everywhere without needing a context, you can use this:

```
Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
handler.post(Runnable);
```

Answer (score 0):

I always choose runOnUiThread, I think so is the best way to run something on the same UI Thread.
AsyncTasks are tricky, it's a good idea but if you want to use something new, use loaders or IntentService.

Comment: AsyncTasks are one of the most logical classes out there since they have a linear execution pattern. Execution is as follows: `onPreExecute()` (UI Thread) -> `doInBackground()` (Non-UI Thread) -> once this method finishes it passes off result to `onPostExecute()` (UI Thread). Simple!

Answer (score 0):

Forget about `AsyncTask`, it's not for running code in the UI thread, but running code in a background thread starting the `AsyncTask` **from** the UI thread.

Regarding the other options, feel free choosing any of them. If you are dealing with a `View` object, it is likely you are already on the UI thread. Therefore, you better keep a reference to the `Activity` context from the other thread and call **runOnUiThread**.

Answer (score 0):

I will recommend you to use [AsyncTasks](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html), they were designed to do hard work in other thead ([doInBackground()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#doInBackground%28Params...%29)) and then syncronize with UI thead to push work results ([onPostExecute()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onPostExecute%28Result%29)), and of course you can periodically update UI with work progress ([onProgressUpdate()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onProgressUpdate%28Progress...%29)).

If you want to run more than one AsyncTask concurrently on Android Version greater than HONEYCOMB, you can use my small lubrary: [Android-AsyncTask-Executor](https://github.com/artem-zinnatullin/Android-AsyncTask-Executor)